# How to Update Ordered Collection of data against other collection of data - using Map Object

Tags: javascript, arrays, data-structures, ecmascript-6

I need to hold ordered data about persons, which i should be updating against data that is fetched from the server. The way the data is structured now, in the client side:

**Anonymous Objects Array:**

```
const clientData = [{
        id: 1,
        employed: true
    },
    {
        id: 2,
        employed: false
    },
    {
        id: 3,
        employed: true
    },
    {
        id: 4,
        employed: false
    }
]
```

Data coming from the server would look like that:

```
   const serverData = [
{
    id: 2,
    newEmployedStatus: true
},
{
    id: 3,
    newEmployedStatus: false
},
]
```

that way, updating my collection forces me to use 2 nested loops.
one loop will iterate over the server array, and for each iteration, i would *search* its corresponding by iteration. like so:

```
// Very Verbose
serverData.forEach((serverPerson)=> {
    clientPerson = clientData.find((element)=> {
        return element.id === serverPerson.id
    })
    clientPerson.employed = serverPerson.newEmployedStatus
})
```

i want to avoid those nested loop and the complicated logic, so:

**Object with accessors approach**

```
const clientData = {
    1: {
        employed:true
    },
    2: {
        employed:false
    },
    3: {
        employed:true
    },
    4: {
        employed:false
    }
}
```

but then i wouldn't be able to rely on the order of the elements when i want to print them.

so, there another approach i came to know lately:

**Map Object**

```
const clientDataMap = new Map(
    [
        [1, { employed:true }],
        [2, { employed:false }],
        [3, { employed:true }],
        [4, { employed:false }],

    ]
)
```

Updating the `clientData` will be with reduced complexity:

```
    serverData.forEach((serverPerson)=> {
        clientDataMap.get(serverPerson.id).employed = serverPerson.newEmployedStatus
    })
```

Still able to print the persons in ordered fashion:

```
clientDataMap.forEach((value, key)=> {
    console.log(key + ' = ' + value.employed);
  });
```

To sum the actual question:

1. is it a valid use case to define `clientData` as `Map` , and enjoy
   the benifits of accessors like i am dealing with `Object`, and
   iterate like i am dealing with an `Array`?
2. What are the downsides of using `Map` for that usecase? if any
3. Are there other approaches for this problem that i missed?

Answer (score 0):

You can always access values in a Javascript object by like this:

```
clientData[key]
```

So the "Objects with acessors approach" could be looped through like this:

```
for(var i in clientData) {
    console.log(i + " = " + clientData[i].employed) 
}
```

Comment: yes but i can't guarantee the order of the printing when using objects

Comment: Do you want to print them in order based on the id number?